# Facebook Scraper cannot retrieve image

Tags: facebook-apps, scraper

In my page, I have this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $picURL; ?>"/>
```

Which when executed is rendered like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/556898_400257580012798_100000856787624_1059515_311974781_n.jpg"/>
```

But the Facebook scraper is seeing it like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="">
```

It seems it is not considering images from Facebook.

Comment: Do you have the other required `og:meta` tags?  Could we possibly see your URL?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/265570) but you can't have images hosted on Facebook set as your meta tags.  It used to give you a clearer error message that you couldn't hotlink Facebook images.

Comment: according to you, is there a way that i can display the image using the facebook meta tag??

Comment: the problem is that all my images are comming from facebook cdn

Comment: @BK, can you please place your comments as the answer

Comment: Hello and ggood ay dear Noor - many thanks for the question:  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/265570) but you can't have images hosted on Facebook set as your meta tags. It used to give you a clearer error message that you couldn't hotlink Facebook images.